# How to create single dimensional array in matlab?

Tags: matlab

i want to create a single dimensional array in MATLAB inside for loop, please help with below code:

```
count = 0;  
for i=1:10  
arr = count;  
count = count+1;    
end
```

when i execute this small code i got 9 as result for arr.

Instead of this i want to have an array arr with 10 values of count for each iteration of i, please help.....

Comment: Why don't you just use `arr = (1 : 10)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
arr = zeros(10,1); % to initialize array
count = 0;  
for i=1:10  
arr(i) = count;  
count = count+1;    
end
```

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways to create arrays in Matlab. The ones you will encounter most often are

- via a range expression:

  ```
  a = 1 : 10;    % Creates a row vector [1, 2, ... 10]
  a = (1 : 10)'; % Creates a column vector [1, 2, ... 10]^T.
  ```
- via generating functions:

  ```
  a = zeros(1, 10); % Creates a 1x10 (=row vector) containing 10 zeros.
  a = zeros(10, 1); % Creates a 10x1 (=column vector) containing 10 zeros.
  ```

  Other generating functions are `ones` to create vectors/matrices whose elements are 
  all 1, `rand` to generate vectors/matrices with uniformly distributed random numbers,
  `randn` for random matrices with Gaussian distribution and so on.
- via concatenation (this is **slow**, but easy to implement and sometimes not avoidable):

  ```
  % Create a vector containing the numbers 1, 4, 9, 16, ... 100.
  a = [];
  for idx = 1 : 10
      a = [a, idx^2];   % Creates a row vector.
      % a = [a; idx^2]; % Creates a column vector.
  end
  ```
- via assigning to an array index larger than the current size (again **slow** if 
  done in a loop):

  ```
  % Create a vector containing the numbers 1, 4, 9, 16, ... 100.
  for idx = 1 : 10
      a(idx) = idx^2;
  end
  ```

  **Note:** I'm not sure if this works in every version of Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

In order to assign a value to an array you need to tell matlab where in the array you want it to go.

First, create an array of zeros the right size with

```
arr = zeros(1,10);
```

Then you can assign `count` to element `i` of `arr` with

```
arr(i) = count;
```

So the code you provided becomes

```
count = 0;
arr = zeros(1,10);
for i=1:10
    arr(i) = count;
    count = count + 1;
end
```

Of course, as other people have mentioned, there are much easier ways to do this particular task, such as

```
arr = 0:9;
```

Where `0:9` is matlab shorthand for 'a row-array containing the integers zero through nine'.